# Why is only part of my sprite showing?

Tags: html, css

I created a sprite for my naviagtion bar so that through javascript/Jquery I could easily swip between the hover on/off state. My question is aren't certain of my css showing up css classes  #whatIS1031 #1031Exchange,and #howToStart aren't showing up.

Here is my Html

```
 <ul id="nav">
            <li class="nav-button" id="home"><a href="Index.html"></a></li>
            <li class="nav-button" id="whatIS1031"><a href="whatIs1031.html"></a></li>
            <li class="nav-button" id="1031Exchange"><a href="exchangeRequ.html"></a></li>
            <li class="nav-button" id="typesOfExchange"><a href="typesOfExchange.html"></a></li>
            <li class="nav-button" id="whyCLX"><a href="howToStart.html"></a></li>
            <li class="nav-button" id="howToStart"><a href="whyCLX.html"></a></li>
            <li class="nav-button" id="resources"><a href="resources.html"></a></li>
            <li class="nav-button" id="faq"><a href="fAQs.html"></a></li>
            <li class="nav-button" id="fee"><a href="fees.html"></a></li>
            <li class="nav-button" id="contactUs"><a href="contactUs.html"></a></li>
        </ul>
        <!--End of nav-->
```

Here is my css

```
#home, #home, #whatIs1031, #whatIs1031, #h-1031Exchange, #h-1031Exchange, #typesOfExchange, #h-typesOfExchange, #whyCLX, #h-whyCLX, #h-howToStart, #h-howToStart, #resources, #h-resources, #faq, #h-faq, #fee, #h-fee, #contactUs, #h-contactUs{
    background: url(http://i1287.photobucket.com/albums/a634/debuggingfool/nav_zps03a73d67.png) no-repeat;
}

#h-home{
    background-position: -222px 0;
    width: 225px;
    height: 30px;
}

#home{
    background-position: 0 0;
    width: 225px;
    height: 30px;
}

#whatIs1031{
    background-position: 0 36px;
    width: 225px;
    height: 30px;
}

#h-whatIs1031{
    background-position: -223px -36px;
    width: 225px;
    height: 30px;
}

#1031Exchange{
    background-position: 0 -72px;
    width: 225px;
    height: 30px;
}

#h-1031Exchange{
    background-position: -224px -73px;
    width: 225px;
    height: 30px;
}

#typesOfExchange{
    background-position: 0 -111px;
    width: 225px;
    height: 30px;
}

h-typesOfExchange{
    background-position: -226px -112px;
    width: 225px;
    height: 30px;
}

#h-whyCLX{
    background-position: -227px -150px;
    width: 225px;
    height: 30px;
}

#whyCLX{
    background-position: 0 -150px;
    width: 225px;
    height: 30px;
}

#howToStart{
    background-position: 0 -190px;
    width: 225px;
    height: 30px;
}

#h-howToStart{
    background-position: -230px -189px;
    width: 225px;
    height: 30px;
}

#h-resources{
    background-position: -230px -226px;
    width: 225px;
    height: 30px;
}

#resources{
    background-position: 0 -227px ;
    width: 225px;
    height: 30px;
}

#faq{
    background-position: 0 -264px ;
    width: 225px;
    height: 30px;
}

#h-faq{
    background-position: -230px -263px ;
    width: 225px;
    height: 30px;
}

#fee{
    background-position: 0 -302px ;
    width: 225px;
    height: 30px;
}

#h-fee{
    background-position: -231px -300px ;
    width: 225px;
    height: 30px;
}

#contactUs{
    background-position: 0 -341px ;
    width: 225px;
    height: 30px;
}

#h-contactUs{
    background-position: -231px -337px ;
    width: 225px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Here is my code on codepen http://codepen.io/Austin-Davis/pen/Fdhej

here is a copy of my sprite on photobucket http://s1287.beta.photobucket.com/user/debuggingfool/media/nav_zps03a73d67.png.html

Comment: why dont you make the sprite of the 2 states and write the text manually above the Element? Your approach is not search engine friendly

Comment: as an aside, IDs shouldn't start with numbers

Comment: also note that you might be better off using css's `:hover` pseudo-class rather than doing this with JS.

Comment: I don't deny that's its not search engine friends its just these were the images I was giving.

Comment: You should be using display:block and putting the image on the ANCHOR tag, not the LI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the HTML and CSS for this project deserves an overhaul, but here are the answers to your specific questions:

- `whatIS1031` isn't showing up due to capitalization.  The element's ID has a capital 'S' (`whatIS1031`) while the CSS selector has a lower case 's' (`whatIs1031`).
- `howToStart` isn't showing up because it's missing from the first CSS declaration for the `background:url()`.  Instead, `#h-howToStart` appears twice.

Side note: you should try out Chrome's dev tools or Firebug for Firefox.  Both of them feature ways of inspecting a DOM element to see what CSS styles are applied.  From there you could see which styles are missing.

Comment: further side note: validating html and css is as good as browser tools when fixing problems like this, although browser tools are far superior for most other things.

Comment: Thanks for the answer yours combined with DA response on the #s in id is what ultimately lead me to fixing my issue and Yes I would agree with you my html and css does deserve an overhaul. I'm still new at this and trying to learn a little bit every day.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer! The notes in @Roy's answer are the sort of refactoring I'd recommend, like using CSS instead of JS and use CSS cascading to apply the same style to a group of elements.  I'd also recommend using classes instead of IDs for all your nav elements, that way if you ever have to add a second nav bar (for whatever reason) you won't have to worry about code breaking that assumes there's only one of that particular thing on the page.

Answer (score 2):

In addtion to the specific ID naming issues mentioned here, There is no reason to do this in javascript, as CSS has a perfect solution:

Let's use #home as an example:

```
#home {
    background-position: 0 0;
}

#home:hover {
    background-position: -222px 0;
}
```

Repeat this for every element.
You might also want to optimize your CSS:

instead of applying the background image for every ID specifically -

```
#home, #home, #whatIs1031, #whatIs1031, #h-1031Exchange, #h-1031Exchange, #typesOfExchange, #h-typesOfExchange, #whyCLX, #h-whyCLX, #h-howToStart, #h-howToStart, #resources, #h-resources, #faq, #h-faq, #fee, #h-fee, #contactUs, #h-contactUs{
    background: url(http://i1287.photobucket.com/albums/a634/debuggingfool/nav_zps03a73d67.png) no-repeat;
}
```

use the class you've already applied to your elements:

```
.nav-button {
    background: url(http://i1287.photobucket.com/albums/a634/debuggingfool/nav_zps03a73d67.png) no-repeat;
}
```

also, you don't have to assign the element size for each ID individually, if they're all the same size. just use -

```
.nav-button {
    background: url(http://i1287.photobucket.com/albums/a634/debuggingfool/nav_zps03a73d67.png) no-repeat;
    width:225px;
    height:30px;
}
```